# How to simulate the float value that appears when you type on the input

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, ionic-framework

It is very difficult to understand what I intend to do. I would like to simulate the float value that appears when you type on the input, but depending on what you want the person to load certain values in an array I define and enable the individual to select it. A kind of self correction.
I have a registration form in which you must choose an organization. These organizations are loaded into an array and need to appear by the user filter. Something very similar to this:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Buscar" ng-model="search.name">
<a class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="lugar in organizations_all | filter:search">

http://codepen.io/jpmckearin/pen/xbraQr?editors=101
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I need to know if I can simulate something like that or is there any plugin for that!

Comment: Are you talking about an autocomplete form? It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: Of course, what I need it is that as you type the user will give him suggestions to auto, auto correction like the Smartphone

Comment: So, you mean like Jquery Autocomplete? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: wooow! @Clyff thanks bro!! please I leave it as an answer, I served much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess, you need this,

```
    <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar" ng-model="search.name">
<a class="item item-avatar" ng-repeat="lugar in organizations_all | filter:search.name">
```

Notice, I've changed the "filter:search" to "filter:search.name". This is to bind the input value, i.e., the model in the search box, (search.name) to the list of all the names in organizations_all.
hope this helps.